# Installing Windows Server for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, installation, virtual-machine, windows-server

I want to install Microsoft SharePoint 2016 on my computer. To do this, first I need to install Windows Server. And I have 2 questions about doing it in the best way:

1.Which version should I choose - Windows Server 2012 (R2) or 2016?

2.Should I install it directly on computer as a second system OR install it on virtual machine (VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Windows Server 2016.  In general the latest Operating System has better security and Microsoft support sunsets at a later date.
2. Either is fine.  Just keep in mind, if you install on a virtual machine, make sure you do not use dynamic memory.  [SharePoints distributed cache has problems with vms using dynamic memory and Microsoft does not recommend.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621103.aspx#Anchor_5)